# split string before hyphen - asp.net c#

Tags: c#, .net, split

I have a string :

```
10989898 - test1
```

or another example:

```
123178239182 - test2
```

I need the output like this:

In first case:

```
10989898
```

In second case:

```
123178239182
```

means the value before hyphen. How can I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
string result = theString.Substring(0, theString.IndexOf("-")).Trim();
```

Comment: +1 for remembering to Trim().  Just because you can't see that space doesn't mean it's not there.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the String Split method:

```
string[] splitString = string.split('-');

string requiredString = splitString[0];
```

Comment: This is bad, your creating a throwaway array for no reason

Comment: Meh only a few bytes

Answer (score 3):

```
string s = "10989898 - test1";
string str = s.Substring( 0, s.IndexOf( "-" ) ).Trim();
```

Comment: Needs a trim or the result will still have the space at the end

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/98Snm/2/

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {


        });
        function replaceFunc() {
            var s = document.getElementById("foo1").value;
            alert(s.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""));
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="replace non-numeric" onclick="replaceFunc()" />
<input type="text" id="foo1"  />
</body>
</html>
```

**Update**

```
Regex reg = new Regex("[^0-9]", RegexOptions.Singleline);
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("123 -test 456", "[^0-9]", ""));
```